# NFC typeb card not getting detected by any NFC application (like:nfctaginfo)

Tags: android, nfc

I am working on NEXSUS-S_4.0.4,need to read typeB(ISO 14443) card's data and display some info stored on card.But my card is not getting detected on my application or on any other downloaded from android-market(like:NFC tag info from NXP). All other card are working fine..

I thank you in advance, Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That could simply be the antenna which may not have a good tuning for the tags you want to read. (ISO14443-B aren't that common...)

To be sure that it is not a software problem you can try to replace the antenna. To do so:

- Remove the back-cover of the Nexus-S. You should see the antenna and the contacts to the NFC daugterboard.
- Take a piece of isolated wire, approx 25cm long. Make two windings, diameter around 4 to 6 cm and connect this to the antenna pins.
- Try to read your B-tag. The phone should now detect the tag and IO via IsoDep should be possible.

This improvised antenna will very likely work better than the built-in one because the built-in one is very close to other metal parts which degrade the antenna-performance.

Comment: btw: I know that the Nexus-S can read Type-B with the above hack because I've done that. You will however not be able to connect to the tag via android.nfc.tech.NfcB as this is not supported at the moment. IsoDep otoh works.

Comment: hello Nils Pipenbrinck it worked!!!!! thanks a lot. Is there any scope in Android SDK/NDK that we can manage NFC antenna power so that TypeB card can be detected...

Comment: Unfortunately not, all you can do is to wait for hardware that has a better antenna.

Comment: hi @Nils Pipenbrinck ,needs your help again. Now I have Samsung Galaxy S3,and need to do read same TypeB card. I have a problem with that too ,have a look on this link:
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12103521/android-isodep-isconnected-returns-false-and-maximum-transceive-length0-byte?lq=1"

Answer (score 0):

To properly perform an anticollision on a Type B tag, you need to provide the AFI (or AID may be called).  It is a single byte that defines the family of application you're looking for.  without that the tag will not respond.

Admittedly, I don't know the Android NFC library too intimately, but there may perhaps be a way to specify this when trying to detect/read a tag.  Android 4.4 has something called reader-mode, and perhaps that can be put into a Type-B polling mode for a given AFI.